# Hyperledger composer with swarm network always rendering "MVCC_READ_CONFLICT"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have currently implemented Hyperledger composer using a swarm docker network on two different host.

My policy is as follow :

```
{
"identities": [
{
    "role": {
        "name": "member",
        "mspId": "Org1MSP"
    }
},
{
    "role": {
        "name": "member",
        "mspId": "Org2MSP"
    }
}
],
"policy": {
    "2-of": [
    {
        "signed-by": 0
    },
    {
        "signed-by": 1
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

I only have one Peer per organization.

Every time I am trying to add something to the ledger I am having back this `error` :

> "Error: Error trying invoke business network. Error: Peer :8051 has rejected transaction '74b678f25c806d3c4677cb76df41902f79399b4f0f0a4560b0c2431908beab36' with code MVCC_READ_CONFLICT"

If anyone have any clues about it would be really awesome !

Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: sounds like your 'EDIT' is your answer - perhaps you need to post it in 'ANSWER' if that is the case.

Comment: just removed the edit and added the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**:

I made a really silly mistake my docker peer container of Org2 was mapped to the CouchDB of my Org1.